# How to handle OOP in this particular situation

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, dependency-injection, drupal

I have to integrate my Drupal application with a third party API through Soap and Rest services.

I would like to be more orthogonal as possible! But i'm not satisfied what i come out with, and I'm asking help here because i don't want to loose too much time with this.

these are my abstract Rest and Soap  services:

```
 abstract class RestService {

  protected $config;

  protected $httpClient;

  public function __construct(ConfigFactoryInterface $configFactory) {
    $this->config = $configFactory->get('third_party.rest_service');
    $this->httpClient = new Client(['base_uri' => $this->setBaseUri()]);
  }

  protected abstract function setBaseUri();

}

abstract class SoapService {

  protected $client;

  protected $credentials;

  public function __construct(ConfigFactoryInterface $configFactory) {
    $config = $configFactory->get('third_party.soap_service');
    $this->client = new SoapClient($config->get('wsdl_url'));
    $this->credentials = new SoapCredentials();
  }

}
```

and now the "specialized" services:

```
class AuthService extends RestService {

  protected function setBaseUri() {
    return $this->config->get('auth_basepath');
  }

  public function getAccessToken() {
    $accessToken = $this->config->get('access_token');

    if (!$this->isTokenValid($accessToken)) {
      $accessToken = $this->refreshToken();
    }

    return $accessToken;
  }

  protected function isTokenValid($accessToken) {...}

}


class ContactsService extends SoapService {

  public function __construct(ConfigFactoryInterface $configFactory, AuthService $authService) {
    parent::__construct($configFactory);

    $this->credentials->password = $authService->getAccessToken();
  }

  public function ... {}

}


class EventsService extends RestService {

  protected $accessToken;

  public function __construct(ConfigFactoryInterface $configFactory, AuthService $authService) {
    parent::__construct($configFactory);

    $this->accessToken = $authService->getAccessToken();
  }

  protected function setBaseUri() {
    return $this->config->get('events_basepath');
  }

  public function getEvents(array $filters = null) {...}

}
```

As you can see AuthService is used for get Access Token and use it in both soap and rest authenticated api calls, but it extends RestService as EventsService already does.

My doubt is in **EventsService** actually, i don't know if it's a good practice do depencency injection of a class (AuthService) that extends the same class of the "container" (EventsService itself).

I know it could be a strange use case but: what would you do in this situation?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Good or best is always subjective. First, does your code work? That's the most important part. To your other question, yes, it is totally fine for class `A` and `B` to extend `C`, and for class `A` to depend on class `B`. As long as nothing results in a circular dependency you should be okay. If you stored any static state you might be in trouble, but that could be set for DI in general, too.

Comment: I'd suggest to use composition over inheritance here. Meaning you implement `RestService` as a non-abstract class and inject it rather than extend it. That way you have better control over where you can and want to access it.

Comment: @ChrisHaas yes the code works! I was just worried for class "A" to depend on class "B" which extends the same class! Sorry for the question but, what you mean for "If you stored any static state you might be in trouble"? Thank you for your help

Comment: @PtrTon RestService is used just to create the Guzzle client with "dynamic" base uri so i don't know how it could be helpful injected in the other services.
Where would you inject the RestService, how would you use it?
Thank you for your help

Comment: @lostprophet90 usually you'd inject the base uri into the `RestService`. Then you'd configure multiple instances of `RestService` in your DI-container. That way you can inject the right instance of the service where you need it.